# How to create a JasperReports report with multiple language support?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, multiple-languages

I am newbie to *JasperReports* and I have this problem creating a single report with *multiLingual* support. It works when I create *separate reports* for each language. But I need it to be done with a single report. I found in some article, it was mentioned that we should import a  *Unicode font* as *.jar* file and that would make the report support multiple languages. But that did not work.

I went through several articles and nothing helped.

Comment: Could you also, tell the reason `DownVoter`? Whats wrong with my question?

Comment: There is no need to use Dynamic Reports, see the proposed duplicate, you use $R{} syntax (hence a resource bundle), this is documentation http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/i18n/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to use Jasper Reports? If it is not, I was using a couple of years ago [Dynamic Reports](http://www.dynamicreports.org)

It give you opportunity to programmatically creates your reports. That way you can internationalize your labels, messages etc and in your code load appropriate resource file and use it with your code for generating reports. You do not have to use jrxml files.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion `nick`. Based on the link you gave,DynamicReports seems good. But my requirement is to use Jasper Report. Thats the problem. Is there any way to do it with `Jasper Report` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, my use case was to dynamically create reports in run-time (include some columns based on user input and other not etc) so I used Dynamic Reports. After that I always use it :)

Comment: Good for you `nick79`. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Note you can internationalize your report also without Dynamic Reports, there is no need to use it for only this purpose (see also my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974058/how-to-create-a-jasperreports-report-with-multiple-language-support#comment74979648_43974058) under question)

Comment: I didn't says that Dynamic Reports should be used because of internatiailiazation, but that it is flexible solution and internatiailiazation could be easily achieved.